# How do I automatically instantiate a singleton after a build?

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton, build-automation, instantiation

I have an ASP.NET 2 C# application that uses a Singleton to load a large list of Data from a Database.

The first request for this singleton very slow (as expected). The subsequent ones are very fast. Is there anyway to instantiate the singleton as soon as the project is built?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of populating a singleton from the database directly after it has been built without running the actual application. You could potentially speed it up by having the singleton be populated on a seperate thread from the rest of the application (in `Application_Start`) this however will not solve the slowdown issue if the singleton is used before it is fully loaded (and also requires the addition of locking logic).

Is there a specific reason why you're loading a large amount of data from the database into the singleton?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic "Without running the application" - WebActivator does not go around this limitation and still requires the application to start up.

Comment: how would WebActivator usage result in Visual Studio outputing a "build failure" if code in App_Start throws an exception then?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic WebActivator hooks into the application startup, as per their wiki / source code `And that's it! Now your code will be called early on when the app starts.` / `[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebActivator.PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")]` it will run before `Application_Start` but it will still only run once the application is starting - are you publishing your site?

Comment: @Chris VS cannot output a build failure for code in App_Start throwing an exception - it doesn't run until the app starts.  It's possible if you use the development web server (and have it open) that it automatically starts the app up when you rebuild, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny so you're stating I'm making the build failure information up in my answer? You're most certainly wrong, and I do not use the development web server or IIS express, I host in full iis. It probably does require the site to not be completely idled out that asp.net has shutdown.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic No, I'm suggesting that something is starting up your web app. The compiler does not execute code in App_Start, it has to run within the web environment. Something is certainly causing your app to start up.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I created a new project and put "throw new Exception()" in the App_Start, and I have no issues building.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Also, new versions of IIS have options to make your website "always live", which *will* cause startup immediately, however this is almost certainly off by default.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny did you run the site once so it was actually hosted by IIS? And have it configured to run as a virtual directory directly from the project binaries?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Yes, I hit it and tried it in IIS, IIS Express and the WebDev server. Not sure what you mean by "directly from the project binaries".

Comment: @DannyTuppeny that you have the project itself directly configured in visual studio to be a virtual directory for IIS.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Yes, that's right. I went into project settings, picked IIS, gave the virdir a name, and clicked the "Created Virtual Directory" button.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* put the code to populate the singleton in the `Application_Start` method in global.asax.cs.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx):

> Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache and initializing static values.

Answer (score -2):

Create it as an App_Start configuration class with [WebActivator](https://bitbucket.org/davidebbo/webactivator).

Assuming your application is setup as a virtual directory the code in App_Start will be called immediately after build.

Note, this will give you the appearance that your builds are "slow". Also note, if you get an exception during this code you will actually get a "build failure" with an arcane error message similar to:

`Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.. ASPRUNTIME    ProjectName`

This is means you need to browse to your app in a browser to see the real error message.

We encountered all of this when we tied in EF Migrations into a App_Start configuration.

Comment: App_Start code does not run as part of the build, it runs at app startup. It's possible if you use the development web server (and have it open) that it automatically starts the app up when you rebuild, but I haven't tested this.